# Static initialization of properties files fails with ant build

Tags: java, ant, testng

I have a small java project which I execute using TestNG + Eclipse, and it works well.
I have externalized test data using properties file and I initialize it in one static block of my test class -

```
public class SanityTest extends SelTestCase {

static Properties properties = new Properties();
static String pickUp;
static String dropOff;

static {
    try {
        properties
                .load(SanityTest.class
                        .getResourceAsStream("/com/product/testdata/testdata.properties"));
        pickUp = properties.getProperty("pickUp");
        dropOff = properties.getProperty("dropOff");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Verifies the booking of car on car hire market
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Test
public void testBookingModule() throws Exception {
    // Some tests here
   }
```

But when I execute same using ant build (1.8) I encounter following exception on target "run" -

```
 [testng] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 [testng]   at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
 [testng]   at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
 [testng]   at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
```

I could not figure out much and also checked that "bin" is created and has all respective files.
Is there any thing I missed?

Comment: How have you formatted the content of your prop file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange to me that you have to use the package/directory name to retrieve your file loaded as a resource by the class loader.

Usually when you use getResourceAsStream, you put your data file where your class is, where the .class file is (or in the resource directory and eclipse will copy it at build time), and the you load it by specifying only the name of the file.

Try

```
 properties.load(SanityTest.class.getResourceAsStream("testdata.properties"));
```

where testdata.properties is in the same folder as SanityTest.class

Regards,
 stéphane

Comment: oh, I wanted to segregated my data from classes which is why I kept it in different directory. Else My classes and test data all would be in one package. Do you suggest any other approach then keeping data file in the same package as class?

Comment: You could use eclipse. A typical maven archetype for a project will let you have test resources in a separate forlder, normal resouces in a separate folder, normal application classes in one folder, test classes in another folder. http://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/directory-structure-in-a-project-with-maven/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you get the stream from the property file.
Could this exception come from badly formatted prop file, which leads to null being returned somewhere?

Comment: Well in that case, I should encounter same exception when I try to execute tests using TestNG, but I don't. I encounter exception only when I use ant!

Comment: ok got the answer, since properties files arr not java classes I had to make a copy task so that they would be available in build folder - <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/com/core/uimap" />
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/com/carhiremarket/testdata">
     <fileset dir="${testdata.dir}" />
    </copy>